# Change background color of SearchView button and query

Tags: android, searchview

For some reason my searchview has a white background instead of transparent and I cant seem to get rid of it.  I am using AppCompat theme.  I am using a `ToolBar` manually as my `ActionBar`.

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="com.exposure.controls.ExposureSearchView" />
</menu>
```

[image]

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/app_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="queryBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="submitBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using an outdated version of the SearchView. Have you had a look at using  app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html

Comment: Can you also post the contents of the file: ExposureSearchView

Comment: I believe I am using the new version, check out my class.

Comment: Any clue guys? Still trying over here

Comment: Have tried to make a sample project with this, but my SearchView has transparency. Can you post your build.gradle files?

Comment: Added the build.gradle files

Comment: Have you tried setting the icon to something other than the android system one? A custom search icon perhaps? I've seen some platforms override icons and put backgrounds on them.. Just an idea. I can't see anything wrong with your code. I've implemented the same thing here and its transparent in my example.

Comment: Have you also tested it on a real device? Sometimes what you see in the emulator is not completely accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated these backgrounds to transparent and it worked.

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background" tools:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will work or not, change `<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>` to `<item name="android:background">@color/app_background</item>` in your launch theme

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<style name="searchButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:background">@color/your_color</item>
        <item name="background">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Add this to your style like as

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">  
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/searchButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/searchButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search));
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Activity.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    // Setting up custom search button icon
            int searchImgId = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button;    // I used the explicit layout ID of searchview's ImageView
// Use Whatever icon you want over here in place of ic_search_black
            ImageView v = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_black);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    // Do operation
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```